# UILabel Strike through with UIImage - NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: UILabel with UIImage overlay]

I have researched a lot [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) and many more.

I tried below code as well

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
NSMutableAttributedString *s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:content];
[s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
          value:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green"]]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
_lblTest.attributedText = s;
```

and got the output like [image: this].

I do not need code, but can anyone help me how to figure it out?

Comment: it's static text?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the attached picture what it is supposed to look like? Or is that what you have currently? Also, when you say you "didn't get success" what did you get? Just trying to work out what you're trying to do as you haven't actually said what it is you want to happen.

Comment: @Fogmeister I want the result exactly like attached image. It's a random string UIlabel and for each line of label, I want that background image. hope you get me.

Comment: Do you mean like the highlighter feature that Apple has in their ebooks and reader and stuff?

Comment: @Fogmeister yes but It should be colorwithpatternimage

Comment: OK, cool, what is your code doing? Can you attach a screenshot of what you're getting from that code?

Comment: @Fogmeister can you please update my question as I'm not able to upload images.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a couple of things for this I think.

First configure your `green` image to make it stretch and tile properly. Do that in the asset catalog. Hit the button "show slicing" that will allow you to fix the right hand side of the image to add the end onto it.

Second it looks like your image is too tall so make it shorter. You'll have to do this manually somehow and I'm not 100% sure if there's a dynamic way of doing it.

If you make sure the image has the same height as a line of text then you will get that repeating pattern properly.

There may be a better way of doing this but this should work for now.